# text under picture not appearing and not scrolling

Tags: html, css

I am making a website but I am unable to make it scroll, there are texts under the picture but it's still not scrolling
Btw it isn't scrolling on my laptop or any other device
I am not sure what is wrong with my website, I have lots of text stretching beyond the bottom of my visible screen but the scroll bar won’t appear and I tried playing around with various “overflow” possibilities but couldn’t figure it out.
can someone help me please
plz if you know the answer tell me
here is the code so plz help

Comment: You duplicated the opening `<header>` tag, so `main` is now part of your outer `header` element as well, but I doubt that's what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Hi setup main in your style like this ?

```
main{
    width:100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: your welcome.... do you mind to check the right answer?

Comment: It is just that i had an extra <header> without its closing tag that is why it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You had an error in you HTML file. You had:

```
  <body>
    <header>
      <header>
      </header>
   </body>
```

Obviously it's not going to work if you have two opening tags, and only one closing tag. Remove one of the opening tags, and it will work.

Happy coding!